# Multiplying dictionary by an integer

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a new dictionary that is a modification of an original dictionary. Below is sample code.

```
alex = {
    'salary' = 50
    'money' = 40
    'saving' = 60
    'debt' = 20
}

    crisis = 2

  #where newalex is the result of alex * crisis

newalex = {
    'salary' = 100
    'money' = 80
    'saving' = 120
    'debt' = 40
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a dictionary comprehension:

```
newalex = {key: value * crisis for key, value in alex.items()}
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- this multiplies every value with "crisis".
```

Comment: And is it possible to change crisis for another dictionary, multiplying each value in alex by a unique value, linked by their keys?

Comment: yes, you just change it to `newalex = {key: value * crisis[key] for key, value in alex.items()}` (assuming that `crisis` is a dictionary with the same keys as `alex`).

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful

Answer (score 3):

you could subclass dict:

```
>>> class muldict(dict):
...  def __mul__(self, integer):
...   return muldict([[key, self[key] * integer] for key in self])
... 
>>> alex = muldict({'salary': 50, 'money': 40, 'saving': 60, 'debt': 20})
>>> alex * 2
{'salary': 100, 'money': 80, 'debt': 40, 'saving': 120}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways about this, (that I know :P)

## firstly...

You have a function that takes a dictionary as an argument,

creates a new dictionary,

iterates over the old dictionary; taking the value, multiplies that value by a factor,

then you return the new dictionary.

## alternatively...

Instead of creating a new dictionary, do the same opperations on the local dictionary that is parsed in the function.

here are my examples...

```
def mult_dictionary_new(dictionary,x):
    new = {}
    for key in dictionary:
        new[key] = dictionary[key] * x
    return new
```

and the alternate solution...

```
def mult_dictionary_modify(dictionary,x):
    for key in dictionary:
        dictionary[key] *= x
    return dictionary
```

edit 2:

## further moar!

if you want to multiply a dictionary by another dictionary, change the function like so.

```
def mult_dictionary(a,b):
    for key in b:
        a[key] *= b[key]
    return a
```

this will work so long as 'b' is an element of 'a'. ie every key in 'b' is a key in 'a'.

end edit 2

hope this helps :D

Connor

edit 1: I suggest you use functions because if you're looking to do bulk operations on various dictionaries, it will be a lot easier.

sure a one line solution is likely what you need, but having your program have functions with meaningful names is a huge advantage when it comes to trouble shooting.

## plus...

make sure you're creating your dictionaries like so...

```
dict = {'key': value,
        'another key': anothervalue}
```

instead of...

```
dict = {'key' = value}
```

keys are assigned using a colon ':' not an equals '=', and every element in the dictionary needs to be separated with a comma ','

you can also assign keys to values by doing...

```
dict['key'] = value
```

Comment: No trouble at all :D, always glad to help.
If at any time you have any other troubles with Python, or just general queries, feel free to email me: 6ixpage@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This is for python2.7

```
newalex = {}
crisis = 2
for key, val in alex.iteritems()
    newalex[key] = val * crisis
```

This is for python3.4

```
newalex = {}
crisis = 2
for key, val in alex.items()
    newalex[key] = val * crisis
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using a [`dictionary comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> alex = {'salary': 50, 'money': 40, 'saving': 60, 'debt': 20}
>>> crisis = 2
>>> new_alex = {k:v*crisis for k, v in alex.items()}
>>> print(new_alex)
{'money': 80, 'salary': 100, 'saving': 120, 'debt': 40}
```